# Get list of data in different sections on scrapy

Tags: python, asynchronous, web-scraping, scrapy

I need data scrape in different sections of a site. In first section, I get data from a customer and the id of your orders. With this id, I access a second section and get the items details from the orders. So, I need to concatenate the result of a dict "customer" with a list of "orders" with a list of "itens".

Basically, my algorithm is:

```
def parse1(self, response):
    customer['data'] = response.xpath("path to customer data").extract()
    customer_orders = response.xpath("path to customer orders")
    for index, customer_order in enumarate(customer_orders):
         id = customer_order.xpath('path to order id').extract_first()
         customer['orders'].append({'id' : id})
         yield scrapy.FormRequest(url="www.url.com/orders"+id, callback=self.parse2, method='GET', meta= {'customer': customer})

def parse2(self, response):
    customer = response.meta['customer']
    customer['orders']['items'] = []  
    for index, order_item in response.xpath("path to order items"):
           customer['orders']['items'].append({"items_details": order_item.xpath("path to items details").extract_first()})
    yield customer
```

But I can't code this logic with Scrapy asynchronous architecture. The closer of this what I got it was print many times the same costumer dict in result. Anybody can help a to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have A and B type requests for 1 item you have two chain requests to act in order: first crawl A then crawl B N-times:

```
customer -> N order pages -> 1 item
```

So your crawl logic is:

1. Get customer data
2. Get orders ids
   2.1 pop order id
   2.2 crawl order id
   2.3 attach order details to #1 customer data
3. return customer data with order data

In scrapy it would look something like:

```
def parse_customer(self, response):
    # find root customer data
    customer = {}
    # find order ids
    orders = [1,2,3]
    # schedule first order request and start order scraping loop
    first_order = order_url + orders.pop(0)
    yield Request(
        first_order, 
        self.parse_orders, 
        meta={'orders': orders, 'item': customer},
        )

def parse_orders(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    remaining_orders = response.meta['orders']
    # first loop it's [1, 2] but finally it'll be []
    if not remaining_orders:  # all orders are scraped -> save item
        yield item
        return

    # attach found order details to root customer item we have
    found_orders = ...
    item['orders'].expand(found_orders)

    # scrape next order
    next_order = order_url + orders.pop(0),
    yield Request(
        next_order,
        self.parse_orders, 
        meta={'orders': orders, 'item': item},
        )
```